# Oracle SQLDeveloper locks up when using copy/paste

Tags: database-administration, sqldeveloper

SQL Developer keeps locking up when I copy/paste text in a worksheet.  It happens when I past into SQL Developer from itself or from another application and also when I past from Developer into another app.  Sometimes it locks up when I hit Ctrl+c (without yet hitting Ctrl+v.) When it's locked Developer is completely unresponsive.  It will not Close and has to be Terminated.  Google is unhelpful... Is this a known issue and how can I fix?

Windows XP, SQL Developer 1.0.0.14.67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be lots of problems here:

First, that is an old, old version - any chance you can upgrade to at least [1.5](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html), or even better give the [2.1 RC](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index21_RC1.html) a shot?

Second, as this is a java app - what VM is it using? In my experience SQL Developer is one of the most picky java apps I have used about what VM it runs on or has issues with. I would recommend grabbing one of their builds that includes a VM just to see if the problem goes away.

Third, are you pasting rich text by chance? Try pasting in from Notepad or something similar to make sure it is just plain text on the clipboard. I have seen many applications struggle to convert between RTF/HTML and whatever they use natively and hang up as they attempt to process the information on the clipboard.

Comment: I'll check the VM when I get back to work after the holiday break.  Going to mark this as good since it's at least plausible.  I have lots of JVMs/JDKs loaded and I didn't specify one so it could be using any one of them.  I'm sure it's not rich text causing the issue (first thing I tried was notepad.)  Not sure if I can upgrade the developer... That's the version that was provided by my company.  I'll check if we have something newer available.  Thanks for the advice.  Suspecting the JVM never crossed my mind.