# Ctrl v does not work in ORACLE SQL Developer

Tags: copy-paste, sqldeveloper

I cannot get paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to work in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: This used to work in the older versions.  My 3.0.04 version, which is the latest, last updated in March 2011, fails to allow this functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQLDeveloper locks up when using copy/paste](https://superuser.com/questions/86127/oracle-sqldeveloper-locks-up-when-using-copy-paste)

Answer (score 5):

try:
Tools -> Preferences -> Accelerators -> Load Preset -> Default -> OK

Comment: I was banging my head on this!! Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of SQL Developer are you using ? Are you encountering any error message? Or the paste function does not work? Older versions of SQL Developer had a bug which resulted in Paste functionality not working. An [earlier question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/86127/oracle-sqldeveloper-locks-up-when-using-copy-paste) recommends use of the JVM provided by Oracle SQL Developer. I'd suggest to [upgrade to the latest version](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer (people, please upvote):

1. Close the table if you have it open
2. Click the table name in the Connections pane
3. Click the Data tab (only) and do no other clicks
4. Hit Control-A on the keyboard
5. Hit Control-C on the keyboard
6. Paste the data into another application

If there are any clicks between steps 3 and 4, the Control-A will usually be disabled.  Once disabled, I'm not sure how to enable without closing the table and re-opening it.

Answer (score 1):

this solution will preserve your actual Key Configuration settings:

1) follow the menu: Tools -> Preferences -> Key Configuration

2) fill the item "Edit / Paste" with Ctrl+V combination

Actually you may need to fill also "Edit / Copy", "Edit / Cut", "Edit / Select All" etc. to feel more comfortable.

If you're not interested in saving your previous Key Configuration settings than just follow Tools -> Preferences -> Key Configuration and press "Reset to Default..." button

Answer (score 0):

If your productor is the PL/SLQ developer version 9,

Go to [tool -> preferance -> User interface -> key configuration]
and click the "Reset to Default" button.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue recently and wanted to update the answer for the most recent Oracle SQL developer commands:

Tools->Preferences->Shortcut Keys

By default, I had two entries for the Edit-Copy command. One was Ctrl-C , one was Ctrl-Insert.

I deleted the Ctrl-Insert row and now copy paste worked each time , when previously it only worked once every 3 times?

Answer (score -1):

Go to tool > preference > user interface > key configuration and press Reset to default.

[image: [1]Este es una imagen de referencia]